# How to have combobox in group policy template adm having different display name and suggestions

Tags: windows, admin, group-policy, gpo

I have the combobox in adm file in the similar fashion, however I need different values for each of the suggestions

For ex: If display name is C registry value has to be C language

```
COMBOBOX
     VALUENAME "Programming Languages"
      SUGGESTIONS
               "C" "C++" "C#" 
      END 
SUGGESTIONS
```

How do I achieve this

Answer (score 1):

We can implement using dropdown list

```
DROPDOWNLIST
            VALUENAME "Programming Languages"
            ITEMLIST
             NAME "C++"                     VALUE "CPLUSPLUS" 
             NAME "C"                       VALUE "C Language"
             NAME "C#"                   VALUE "CSharp"
             
            END ITEMLIST
         END PART
```